# Task.Factory.StartNew y bloqueo de UI

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, multitasking

tengo un problema. Estoy en una aplicacion WPF y quiero hacer una consulta SQL en segundo plano, todo esto ya lo tengo, el problema que al momento de hacer la "consulta", la UI se me tilda y no se porque, si la estoy haciendo en otro hilo.

Este codigo de aca funciona, pero me tilda la UI. En cambio si borramos el FOR y ponemos un Thread.Sleep(5000) se ve perfecto el funcionamiento. Estoy usando NET4.0

```
    private void Buscar()
    {

        ShowMessage = "Buscando...";

        IsBusy = true;

        ShowProgressRing = true;

        Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {

            //Thread.Sleep(5000); // Simulate SQL query

            Articulos = new ObservableCollection<Articulo>();

            for (var i = 0; i < 500; i++)
            {
                Articulos.Add(new Articulo
                {
                    Codigo = i.ToString(),
                    NombreDelArticulo = "PRODUCT NAME",
                    PrecioFinal = 1m
                });
            }

            IsBusy = false;

        }).ContinueWith(x =>
        {


        }, TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

He probado tu código en un proyecto WPF targeting NET Framework 4 en VS 2015 update 4, y no sé que entiendes por "tildar" el UI, pero lo que ocurre es que el usuario no tiene noticia de que ha terminado la búsqueda porque no se ejecuta ningún código en la Acción de Continuación. Así que al terminar la búsqueda, todo continua igual y parece que no se ha hecho nada.

Tal como lo has codificado, la Acción de Continuación se ejecuta en el hilo del UI al terminar la búsqueda, así que ahí puedes cambiar los elementos gráficos, y por lo menos tendrías que mostrar los artículos encontrados vinculando la colección Articulos a un elemento gráfico como un ListView o un GridView.

Por ejemplo:

```
 private void Buscar()
    {

        ShowMessage = "Buscando...";

        IsBusy = true;

        ShowProgressRing = true;

        Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {

            //Thread.Sleep(5000); // Simulate SQL query

            Articulos = new ObservableCollection<Articulo>();

            for (var i = 0; i < 500; i++)
            {
                Articulos.Add(new Articulo
                {
                    Codigo = i.ToString(),
                    NombreDelArticulo = "PRODUCT NAME",
                    PrecioFinal = 1m
                });
            }

            IsBusy = false;

        }).ContinueWith(x =>
        {

            MessageBox.Show("Búsqueda finalizada, pulse para ver los artículos encontrados");
            ArticulosLW.ItemsSource = Articulos;

        }, TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Lo que te está ocurriendo, es que estás modificando dentro de una tarea, un objeto que no creó esa tarea, en este caso el objeto Articulos, que debe de ser una propiedad del objeto Window.

Esto lo arreglas, creando una tarea que cree un objeto como el que necesitas (en este caso un ObservableCollection y que cuando finalice lo devuelva y se lo instancie al que tú necesitas alimentar. Con async/await, es muy sencillito.

Aquí tienes tu ejemplo modificado:

```
private async void Buscar()
{

    ShowMessage = "Buscando...";

    IsBusy = true;

    ShowProgressRing = true;

    Articulos = await Task<ObservableCollection<Articulo>>.Run(() =>
    {

        //Thread.Sleep(5000); // Simulate SQL query

        var newArticulos = new ObservableCollection<Articulo>();

        for (var i = 0; i < 500; i++)
        {
            Articulos.Add(new Articulo
            {
                Codigo = i.ToString(),
                NombreDelArticulo = "PRODUCT NAME",
                PrecioFinal = 1m
            });
        }

        return newArticulos;

    });

    IsBusy = false;

    MessageBox.Show("Búsqueda finalizada, pulse para ver los artículos encontrados");
    ArticulosLW.ItemsSource = Articulos;


}
```